# Percorrer JSON com objetos em Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, map

Boa noite, pessoal..
Estou iniciando no JS com VUE.. Tenho uma situação que não consegui resolver:

Tenho 1 objeto JSON com 2 objetos que vêm como retorno:

```
retorno = {
obj1 =    {
    "permitido":false,
    "msg": "erro"
}, 
obj2 = {
    "permitido":true,
    "msg": "ok"
} 
}
```

como faço pra percorrer/mapear e testar a chave "permitido" para todos os elementos que vieram?
Quando o retorno era somente um objeto, eu mapeava assim:

```
Object.values(retorno['obj1'].map(elm => {}...
```

Podem me ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar `Object.keys()` para obter todas as keys que vem no **JSON**, e depois usar um `for` para percorrer esses objetos.

```js
var json = {
    "obj1": {
        "permitido": false,
        "msg": "erro"
    },
    "obj2": {
        "permitido": true,
        "msg": "ok"
    }
}

var keys = Object.keys(json)
for (key in keys){
    if (json[keys[key]].permitido){
        console.log(`Sucesso! (${keys[key]}) = ${json[keys[key]].msg}`)
    } else {
        console.log(`Erro! (${keys[key]}) = ${json[keys[key]].msg}`)
    }
}
```

Comment: Certo. Entendi a lógica. Mas acho que não vai dar certo. É porque nesse retorno se pelo menos um dos objX tiverem o permitido = false, não deve concluir a transação e apresentar a mensagem que veio naquele objX.

Comment: Se você não quer que apareça a mensagem quando `permitido = false`, é só não adicionar o `else`.

Comment: Tudo certo! Obrigado